# how to make small fragment to call on resume when big fragment resumed?

Tags: android

This method doesn't call for second time

```
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setData();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Do both these fragments have the same parent activity?

Comment: this fragment is xml fragment included in large fragment that have the main activity as parent  activity

Comment: Calling lifecycle methods is bad idea. It is better to create some method like update() and call it. Then you can use code like bartol have suggested (you would need cast founded fragments to yours).

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize

```
    @Override
    void onResumeFragments() { 
        for(Fragment frag : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) frag.onResume(); 
    }
```